# How do you port forward from a vpn connection with ddwrt?

Tags: iptables

I have a ddwrt router v24 and build something or other. I can connect to my vpn with it, gives me an ip without a problem (192.168.10.200). I would like to port forward 8080/tcp from the vpn ip/interface into my internal lan 10.0.0.50:80.

I've tried just about every iptables command I can think of and still no luck. It feels like the problem is that things arent traversing from ppp0 into the lan.  Seems like this should be really simple but it has not been.  Thanks.

So far:

iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.10.200 --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.50:80

iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.0.0.50 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you did a copy/paste:

--to 10.0.0.75:50 should be --to-destination 10.0.0.50:80

If not; then:
Can you ping 10.0.0.50 from the router?
Can you ping the router from 10.0.0.50 (ie, does it have a route to 192.168.10.0/24?)

Comment: sorry that was a typo, .50 is correct.

Yes, I can ping the router from 10.0.0.50.

Answer (score 0):

You need one more rule to let out the output traffic :

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -d 10.0.0.50 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.10.200`

Place this rule between the `PREROUTING` and the `FORWARD` rules.
Try to use `-A` (append) argument instead of the `-I` (insert) in all your rules.